# Ammonia in sweat from workout - Protein (Muscle) Loss?

Tags: workout, protein, food

I workout early in the morning for about 1 hour. 
Recently, I've begun noticing ammonia like smell on my towel. I researched and found out that my body is burning amino acids to provide energy during workout. 
So, does this mean that whatever muscle I'm building, is getting burnt away during my workout?

What kind of food should I eat about half an hour before workout to alleviate the ammonia smell? That's as much time as I have in the morning.
All advice welcome, thanks.

Comment: You wot? Wash your towel, wash yourself. It's impossible to 'burn away muscle'. As far as food goes the only diet I know that causes smell issues (sometimes) is the Indian diet.

Comment: What research informed you that you are "burning amino acids"?

Comment: @rrirower: http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/ammonia.htm --- I got it here.

Comment: I don't know whether to believe that article.  It seems to be more anecdotal rather than evidence based.

Comment: @rrirower - That is not the best article, but ammonia smell in sweat has long been known to be a byproduct of protein metabolism rather than carb. Normally the ammonia from protein breakdown gets taken care of in the liver, but during high production (i.e. exercise), it also gets excreted through sweat.

Comment: @JohnP - is it bad to let the protein of my body get broken down? How will that affect my muscles?

Answer (score 1):

Your research is probably leading you to sites with essays like [this one](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/ammonia.htm). The answer is there as well:

> Based on this explanation, it is clear that your sweat will smell like ammonia only if **an excessive amount of amino acids are being used** for energy, or you are **not receiving adequate water**. This helps us find a solution to the problem.

....

> Many people **mistakenly believe that ammonia sweat means that their protein intake is not high enough**. The body will only utilize protein for energy when it does not have a sufficient supply of fats and carbohydrates. Muscles can use glucose and fat for energy, but your brain requires glucose. Since there is no direct metabolic pathway from fat to glucose, your body will use amino acids instead. If your protein intake is high, there is a chance that the amino acids that supply energy will come from ingested food and not your hard-earned muscle tissue - but why take that chance?
>
> Let's look at an oil lamp. If you fill that lamp with Citronella oil, it will have a distinct odor when you light it. To eliminate that odor, do you add more Citronella? No! That's just fanning the flames. You'd use a different type of oil instead. The same goes for the ammonia smell - this is just the smell of amino acids being "burned" in your body. You don't solve that by adding more amino acids. Instead, you need to supply the fuel that your body prefers - the **fuel that can be easily broken down to glucose** in order to supply energy to your muscles and your brain - **carbohydrates**!

**TL;DR**: No, this does not mean your muscles are being broken down, and carbohydrates and sufficient hydration are the keys to avoiding the ammonia smell.

Comment: So, if the problem is less carbs, then will a snack about 1/2 hour before workout be good enough to provide the carbs needed for the exertion?

Comment: Frankly, it will depend on how much energy you use during the workout.